# Basic login form in React.js

Tags: react.js, form, jsx

I have made a very basic login/registration form in React.js.

[image: React.js login form]

The inputted data is send to a Java Spring Boot Rest-API to create an user or to authenticate using JWT. But in this question I want to focus on the React.js code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from "axios"
import Cookies from "js-cookie"

import "../styles/Home.sass"

class Home extends Component {
    
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            message: {},
            inputs: {},
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.Form = this.Form.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        let inputs = this.state.inputs
        inputs[event.target.name] = event.target.value
        this.setState({inputs})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="container">
                <div id="text">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Welcome to Finonline</h1>
                        <span id="slogan">Administrate your personal expenses online.</span>
                        <p>
                            This is a demo-project for my job-application showcasing my skills in full-stack webdevelopment, Java, Spring Boot and React.js.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="form-container">
                    <this.Form />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    Form() {
        const handleSubmit = (event, action) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            
            switch (action) {
                case "register":
                    this.register(this.state.inputs)
                    break
                default:
                    this.login(this.state.inputs)
            }
        }

        return (
            <form onSubmit={(event) => handleSubmit(event, 'login')} >
                <span className="title">Login</span>
                <div className="input-wrapper">
                    <img src="/assets/images/profile.png" alt="" />
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Username" minLength="3" required="" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="input-wrapper">
                    <img src="/assets/images/password.png" alt="" />
                    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" minLength="5" required="" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>
                <div id="form-buttons">
                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event, 'login')} />
                    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Or register" id="registerbtn" onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event, 'register')} />
                </div>
                <span id="message" className={this.state.message["type"]}>
                    { this.state.message["text"] }
                </span>
            </form>
        )
    }

    async register(data) {
        let message = this.state.message

        try {
            const response = await axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/users`,
                    data
                ,
                {
                    insecureHTTPParser: true,
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    }
                })

            if (response.status == 201) {
                message["type"] = "ok"
                message["text"] = "Successfully registered."
                
                this.setState({ message  })
            } else {
                message["type"] = "error"
                message["text"] = "Error: " + response.data
                
                this.setState({ message  })
            }
        } catch (err) {
            message["type"] = "error"
            message["text"] = "Error: This user already exists."
            
            this.setState({ message  })
        }
    }

    async login(data) {
        let message = this.state.message

        try {
            const response = await axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth`,
                    data
                ,
                {
                    insecureHTTPParser: true,
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    }
                })
            
            if (response.status == 200) {
                message["type"] = "ok"
                message["text"] = "Login successful."
                
                this.setState({ message  })
            } else {
                message["type"] = "error"
                message["text"] = "Error: Login failed."
                
                this.setState({ message  })
            }
        } catch (err) {
            message["type"] = "error"
            message["text"] = "Error: Login failed."
            
            this.setState({ message  })
        }
    }
}

export default Home
```

I have made a class extending `Component`. I have two states: `message` which holds the response message from the API and the type (ok/error), and `inputs` which holds the entered input from the user.

- Is this clean React.js code?
- Should the functions `login` and `register` be present in this class?
- Is it okay to have a separate function for the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve you cleanliness by removing some of your redundant patterns and building up robustness.  You have a lot of

```
message["type"] = "ok"
message["text"] = "Login successful."
```

I'd probably pull that into a function.  "type" may benefit from an enumeration with string values.

Your `register` and `login` both have very similar structures that can probably be abstracted.

I'd consider using `response.ok` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok over a manual check of magic status code values.  Otherwise, I might pull those `200`, `201`, etc into their own variables for readability.

`handleSubmit` has a one case `switch`.  There's a number of ways you can do this, but I might consider an object with the functions since they have the same signature.  This could naturally lead into a factory pattern later, e.g. sketching something (didn't check if it runs):

```
const actions = {
    "register": this.register,
    "login" : this.login
}

const actionToCall = actions[action];

if(actionToCall) {
    actionToCall(this.state.inputs)
} else {
    throw new Error("Bad action")
}
```

You could also just use an `if`/`else`, or if you're really wanting to use a switch, explicitly have `register` and `login` cases and the default throw an error.

Having login and register are fine, but you could pull out some classes that have a common interface like "ActionHandler" and use a true factory pattern to build them.  For just two that might be overkill.

`Form` as it's own function is good and I would go further to pull it out to its own component.  It's already operating at that leve, but you've got `Form` tightly coupled with the `Home` state. I'd have `Form` communicate to `Home` by passing `state` as a prop and a callback function which sets the state (this could just be passing in the `setState` function`)